# Python 2.7.8: Printing a sub-dictionary value?

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

I'm using ConfigParser which returns a dictionary of configuration data as such:

```
{'general': {'UserKey': 'thisisatestkey'}}
```

If I want to simply print the value of the UserKey key (in this case thisisatestkey), then I generally just do a `print "Your key is: {0}".format(mydictvar.get('UserKey'))`.

If I just print out the raw dict to a string I get the above.  If I use the print statement above I get result of None since there is no key in the root of the dict called UserKey.  If I `.get('general')` I just get: `{'UserKey': 'thisisatestkey'}`

Obviously I could do a fore loop like so:

```
keydic = cp.get_config_data()

for m, k in keydic.iteritems():
    for s, v in k.iteritems():
        userkey = v
```

and then print userkey which works fine.  But I want to know how I can just avoid having to do the entire for loop first and just print the darned value right inline?  Thanks!

Comment: You mean `mydictvar['general']['UserKey']`? Or, if keys might be missing `mydictvar.get('general', {}).get('UserKey')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
mydictvar['general']['UserKey']
```

Or, if keys might be missing

```
mydictvar.get('general', {}).get('UserKey')
```

`mydictvar['general']` returns a dictionary object; you can then just apply `[...]` to that value to retrieve the next key.

This works in string formatting too:

```
>>> mydictvar = {'general': {'UserKey': 'thisisatestkey'}}
>>> print "Your key is: {0[general][UserKey]}".format(mydictvar)
Your key is: thisisatestkey
```

Answer (score 0):

simply without loop:

```
>>> my_dict = {'general': {'UserKey': 'thisisatestkey'}}
>>> my_dict['general']['UserKey']
'thisisatestkey'
```